# check if db status is correct then dosomething

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am not sure why the code isn't working.
if the rStatus = Reserve show the reservation details
if rStatus = cancelled show label.text and the following

what is not working:
when i enter the page under eg. user="ben12" this user have reservation but the reservation does not appear instead it show user have no reservation which will happen if user reservation status is cancelled.

i have checked further that under user="ben12" it have several cancelled and reserve status, i am not sure if that is the reason why the if statement does not work

my objective is that if user have reservation display the reservation, if not otherwise

This code is under the `Page_Load` of my Reservation.aspx.cs

```
OleDbConnection mDB = new OleDbConnection();
mDB.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source="
    + Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/IESDatabase.accdb");
OleDbCommand cmd; 
OleDbDataReader rdr;
string strUserId = (string)Session["sUserId"];
string strSql = "SELECT rStatus FROM Reservation WHERE rUserId = @UserId "
    + "ORDER BY rStatus DESC;";
cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql, mDB);
mDB.Open();
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
rdr.Read();
Session["rsStatus"] = rdr["rStatus"]; // store the current status
mDB.Close();

if ((string)Session["srStatus"] == "Cancelled")
{
    DetailsView1.Visible = false;
    Label2.Visible = false;
    btnBuy.Visible = false;
    DropDownList1.Visible = false;
    btnCancel.Visible = false;
    lblReserve.Text = "There is no resevation for user " + Session["sUserId"];
}
if ((string)Session["srStatus"] == "Reserve")
{
    lblReserve.Visible = false;
    Label1.Visible = true;
    Label2.Visible = true;
    DetailsView1.Visible = true;
    btnBuy.Visible = true;
    DropDownList1.Visible = true;
    btnCancel.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: What is not working? Did you tried to debug and check the values?

Comment: @boomer when i enter the page under eg. user="ben12" this user have reservation but the reservation does not appear instead it show user have no reservation  which will happen if user reservation status is cancelled. 

i have checked further that under user="ben12" it have several cancelled and reserve status, i am not sure if that is the reason why the if statement does not work.

Comment: karthi diff user have different reservation for say @UserId is used to identify if user have any res

Comment: You need to add Parameter for  @UserId so it would be `cmd.AddWithValue(@UserId, strUserId);` for starters also don't assume things ..wrap the code around a try{}catch{}

Comment: Malcolm this code needs to be seriously cleaned up as well as you need to Debug do not just code and GO...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your session name, here:

```
Session["rsStatus"] = rdr["rStatus"]; // store the current status
```

it should be **srStatus**

Comment: hi just changed it, the problem is still the same

Comment: there is a conflict in the if statement i believe as mentioned user="ben12" it have several cancelled and reserve status

Comment: reader should returned value "reserve" or "cancelled" if cancelled and have remaining reserve item i am not sure how it will react

Comment: Did you debugged your solution to see what the rdr["rStatus"] contains?

Comment: Yes i did debugged it doesn't display any value